# returning a printf(), cannot find symbol

Tags: java, format, return, printf, symbols

```
public String format()
    {
           return printf("%1$10s, %2$10s, %3$10d", getForename(), getSurname(), getAge());
    }
```

I'm trying to return a formatted string. However, printf() is apparently a missing symbol. Any suggestions?

If you need more info I'll provide.

Comment: There's a `System.out.printf()` in Java, but I suspect you're looking for something else as it does not return a `String` but rather prints to `stdout`. See Oli's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean `String.format`, not `printf`.

Comment: @david - no, it wouldn't, because it doesn't return a `String` which is what the OP's code is obviously trying to do.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I thought I had to use printf completely forgetting about String.format